# Background image is too much saturated

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, effects, color-management

Hello I'm having a huge issue with my background image being too saturated and I cannot find anything on this, most likely I'm not searching the right thing.

Given the examples below. One is darker than the other. The more saturated picture (redder) is being outputted in blender 2.81

[image: The Original]

[image]

I have not added any filters at all to make it such color. The compositor just outputs an image to an Alpha over to the composite node. In the viewport, it has the right color. But once composited, it adds the saturation all on its own.

The saturation imbalance does not affect any other part of the render.

I thank you for reading and have an amazing day.

UPDATE: The resolution to this problem was that my exposure in color management was at 1.7 and it was supposed to be at 0. I've been using blender for over 11 years and even with all the new updates. A well-seasoned person can make a mistake. Hope this helps others.

Comment: Go to Render properties and experiment with the Color Management (very bottom section) settings until it looks right. It would probably look better in standard mode (I believe the default is Filmic)

Comment: Thank you so much. I have figured out why it was not working. My exposure in the color balance was set to 1.7 for some reason. I will be updating my question as solved. Thank you so much.